# Posting to Goolge Chat Thread

Tags: google-chat

I am trying, for now via Postman, to post a message back to an existing thread but it always seems to post the message as a separate message, not as a thread reply to the message:

In postman I am using the following as the raw body where x's are replaced by the right space/thread info:

{
"text": "Your message text here",
"thread": {
"name": "spaces/xxxxxxx/threads/xxxxxxx"
}
}

Its status is 200 and posts in the right space without error?

Does anyone know what this could be?

Thanks in advance,

Olly

This appears to post successfully without error (it identifies the thread as a valid one) however it posts as a separate message, not a thread reply.